# how can I get thunderbird's "current tasks" in evolution?

Tags: thunderbird, evolution, task-management, lightning

when using the Tasklist of thunderbird, there is a filter called "current Tasks", which shows task that are unfinished and have a start-date in the past (or no start-date at all).

**Is there are way to have the same filter in the tasklist of evolution?**

There is a filter with the same name in evolution, but it ignores the start-date and instead shows unfinished tasks with a due-date within the next 12 months, which is not what I am looking for

There seems to be [a relevant discussion on evolution's gitlab](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evolution/-/issues/1242) about a possible bug in that direction.

I am using a caldav calendar/tasklist.

here is the filter in thunderbird: [image: "current tasks" in thunderbird]

here is the filter with the same name but different function in evolution: [image: "current tasks" in evolution]

Comment: In the config there is an option, that controls whether task without due-date are shown. When I enable this option, the tasklist still does not behave as expected/desired.